# sed regex match and replace any last digit

Tags: regex, sed

I have lots of file containing following ipaddress, and i want to replace last digit of ip and look like i am having struggle to come up with correct regex

file1

```
IPADDR=10.30.2.26
NETMASK=255.255.0.0
GATEWAY=10.30.0.1
```

I want to replace `10.30.2.26` to `10.30.2.27` using sed but somehow i am missing something, i have tried following.

I have many file which i want to replace and last digit could be anything.

I have tried `sed 's/[^IPADDR].$/7/g' file1`

how do i match anything between `^IPADDR{anything}$` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex, `[^IPADDR]` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that search for any character except those listed between brackets. I'm not sure that's what you want.

You can use an address instead to find lines starting with `IPADDR`(`/^IPADDR/`) and apply the substitution command on it:

```
sed '/^IPADDR/s/[0-9]$/7/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following command:

```
sed -r 's/(^IPADDR=[0-9.]+)([0-9]$)/\17/g' file
```

Prints:

```
IPADDR=10.30.2.27
NETMASK=255.255.0.0
GATEWAY=10.30.0.1
```